# unbelievably simple "if" failing in PHP

Tags: php

I have been banging my head against this one for a while now and have tried many versions of this code. I must be doing something *very* basic wrong ...

```
$pop = FALSE;
$pop = ($visits > 4);

if ($pop){
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'spester') .'/light.js');
}
```

`var_dump($visits, $pop)` gives me

```
int(3) bool(false)
```

... and yet the expression inside my if evaluates.

Of course, if I instead do `if{FASLE}{...}`, then my code behaves as expected ...

Comment: Are you certain the `drupal_add_js` call isn't also occurring somewhere else as well? And have you cleared Drupal's page cache?

Comment: It's not happening here: http://codepad.org/A8F6MZ7S Must be something else, how are you *sure* `if (FALSE) {}` gives different output?

Comment: Put an `echo` in the `if` condition and see if it gets printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that bool is `false`, the `if` body *never* gets executed. You can put a simple tracing `echo` there and you'll see it.

It looks like some other executed code makes you think that the body is executed when in fact it isn't. Or you editing the wrong file. Or forgot to refresh it. Or something else...

Please don't blame PHP, you'll be 99.999% wrong.

Note: I hope FASLE is only a typo in your post. Also, check your warning/error display settings.

Comment: To be fair, he never officially blamed PHP, but `if{FASLE}{...}` is a doozy indeed...

Comment: Thank you for all the advice ... Of course should have put an echo into if itself ...

What I discovered, and need to get to the bottom of, is that drupal is somehow repeatedly calling that function, so that what I got in var_dump($visits, $pop) for a single pageload was:

int(18) bool(true) int(18) bool(true) int(2) bool(false) int(2) bool(false) int(69) bool(true) int(69) bool(true) int(18) bool(true) int(18) bool(true) int(3) bool(false) int(4) bool(false)

wow! something weird happening with my $visits variable! (which is being read from $_COOKIE ...

Answer (score -2):

check the value of @visit variable and spit out the value of $pop. It could be that $visit has wrong value in it.

Also a better condition is

```
if ($pop == true)
{
  //do this 
}
```

Comment: Why is loose comparison better than implicit boolean? Also, the values are right there in OP's `var_dump()`.

Comment: that's exactly the same condition.

Comment: `($pop == true)` is redundant and just there for visual confirmation that you are doing `== true`

Comment: Besides, if you're going to be fussy, `if (true === $pop)` is better anyway. ;)  (The main reason, for anyone wondering, is that putting the constant first is generally a good practice because sometimes people forget the second '=', and `if ($pop = true)` will lead to bugs, while `if (true = $pop)` will cause a 'cannot assign a value to a constant' type of error which is a lot more obvious. So get into the habit of putting the constant first if there is one, and you immediately cut out a whole set of potential bugs from your code.)